# σ-algebra generated by class

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C$ denote the collection of singleton's $\{q\}$, where $q$ is rational; that is,

$$C=\big\{\{q\}:q\in\Bbb Q\big\}$$

Show that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$ is

$$F  = \{ A : A \cap\Bbb Q \ne \varnothing\text{ or }A^c \cap\Bbb Q \ne\varnothing\}\;.$$

Comment: Note that if $A\cap\Bbb Q=\varnothing$, then $A^c\supseteq\Bbb Q$, so $F=\wp(\Bbb R)$. (I assume that you’re taking complements in $\Bbb R$, though you really ought to say so.) Are you sure that you’ve given the definition of $F$ correctly?

Comment: To talk about the generated $\sigma$-algebra you need to talk about "closing under complements", but there is no general and absolute notion of complement. You must specify what is the set against you are complementing. Is it $\Bbb{Q,R,C}$? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest that what you are trying to prove is in fact that
$$
F=\{A\subseteq\mathbb R:A\subseteq\mathbb Q\ \text{or}\ \mathbb R\setminus A\subseteq \mathbb Q\}=\{A\subseteq\mathbb R:A\subseteq\mathbb Q\ \text{or}\ \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\subseteq A\}.
$$